# Python multithreading, global variables, and raw_input in Raspberry Pi

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, global-variables, raspberry-pi, raw-input

I'm completely new in Python and RPi. I'll try to make my question and sample code as general as possible.

I'm working on this implementation where I need three threads to communicate:

The first thread just waits until either of two flags, global variables `flag1` and `flag2`, becomes `TRUE`.

The second thread waits for an input from the user. If the user inputs "a", then flag remains `FALSE`. But if the user inputs any other string, `flag1` becomes `TRUE`.

The third thread looks into a GPIO pin and sets `flag2` to `TRUE` when a push button is pressed.

```
import threading
import time
import RPI.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #set GPIO 11 to PULL-UP input

flag1 = FALSE
flag2 = FALSE

def thread1():
    global flag1
    global flag2

    while 1:

        while flag1 == TRUE:
            print "flag1"
            flag1 = FALSE ##clear this flag
        while flag2 == TRUE:
            print "flag2"
            flag2 = FALSE ##clear this flag
        time.sleep(0.0001)

def button():
    global flag1

    if (GPIO.input(11) == True): #button is NOT pressed
        flag1 = FALSE
    else:
        flag2 = TRUE

    time.sleep(0.0001)

def input():
    global flag2
    x = "a"

    while (flag1 == FALSE) and (flag2 == FALSE):        
        y = raw_input("input: ")

        if x == y:
            print "input is a"
            flag1 = FALSE
        else:
            print "input is not a"
            flag1 = TRUE

t1 = threading.Thread(target = thread1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target = button)
t3 = threading.Thread(target = input)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
while True:
     time.sleep(0.0001)
```

Before coming up with this, I coded the threads independently and they work fine. But I'm having trouble now in combining them in one program and making them communicate. My problem is I think due to the sequential nature of the `raw_input()` function. Is there an alternative to this? I'm using Python 2.7.3 if that helps. Any tips or "programming optimization" would also be appreciated. Thank you!

PS: My hardware for the input emulates a keyboard with carriage return.